# Append digit to a prefix string using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, perl

I need to have a Regular Expression for the below Input and Output

Sample Input:
TEST_ABC
TEST_DEF
TEST_XYZ

Sample Output:
TEST1_ABC
TEST2_DEF
TEST3_XYZ

No Restrictions on sequencing the input parameters.

Comment: Why no loop over your strings and replace "_" with "i_" where i is the loop counter ?

Comment: intend to do with regular expression, as the number of input parameters is not fixed

Comment: Only regex tag? What are you using for replace?

Comment: want to try something like this 
(?(?=(TEST)_(.*)|\G)<TEST><DIGIT_INCREMENTED>_(\1))

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
(?=_)
```

with

```
1
```

`(?=_)` "matches" the **position** before the `_` using a positive look-ahead. It doesn't match any actual characters.

Replacing with `1`, inserts it at the matched position.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tZrERZ/1).

Comment: but how to increment the count for each matched expression

Comment: Well, you asked for a regular expression. And RE isn't a programming language. The logic, and php code, really isn't in the scope of your question. But it should be **really** simple to write ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions do not support incrementing numbers, because regular expressions are about *patterns* not *numbers*.

However, `perl` can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count;

while (<DATA>) {
   s/(?=_)/++$count/e;
   print;
}

__DATA__
TEST_ABC
TEST_DEF
TEST_XYZ
```

Which *inserts* an incrementing count before the first underscore in each line.

As a one liner, this'd be;

```
perl -pe 's/(?=_)/++$c/e'
```